# iPhone Updating Detail View after Parsed XML / Core Data backthread delay

Tags: iphone, core-data, delay, xml-parsing, detailsview

I have a back-thread delay problem where an xml parser operating on a backthread completes parsing the data long after the detailView loads/displays.

Core data is storing initially brief details for a tableListView. When I'm selecting a listItem object at index x, the detailView requires more data for display. It needs to parse more XML, add it to core data and display it in the detail view.

How can I either get the detailView to wait for the data to be available OR reload the detailView when the data becomes available in CoreData? ie What technique?

Answer (score 0):

NSFetchedResultsController will do it automatically after you merge the foreground managed object context with the background context that accepts the parsed data.